# Trying to get property of non-object in Zend Paginator

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-paginator

i am using zend paginator in my app.pagination works well but i get this error Trying to get property of non-object in

```
$user = new Zend_Session_Namespace('user');
$user_id =$user->user_id;
 $DB = Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getDefaultAdapter();
 $select = $DB->select()
     ->from(array('p' => 'phone_service'))
     ->join(array('u' => 'user_preferences'), 'u.phone_service_id = p.phone_service_id')
     ->where('u.user_preferences_name = ?', 'is_user_package_active')
     ->where('p.user_id = ?', $user_id);

     $adapter = new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect($select);
     $paginator = new Zend_Paginator($adapter);
     $this->view->paginator=$paginator;
```

in my view i am doing so

```
 foreach($this->paginator as $record){
 <td><?php echo $record->phone_service_name;?></td>
  <td><?php echo $record->phone_service_type;?></td>
  <td ><?php echo $record->phone_service_Duration;?></td>}
```

which is giving following error

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
```

when i do so in my view

```
var_dump($this->paginator);
 [_tableCols:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )
there are no data of columns
```

Any Hint PLZ ???

Comment: How does your controller tell the paginator which page to get?

Comment: @RockyFord $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(10);
           $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
          $this->view->paginator=$paginator;

Comment: All you can do is start dumping variables until you find what's not working as expected. I personally like the Zend_Debug::dump($var,''); Because it is preformated with pre tags and I can give it a title so I can dump several variables at the same time. It also works in controllers and usually in models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
make it sure column names in DB and in your code are same.mean spelling are same
or $record['phone_service_name']
 once i got this error and the problem was i miss spell column name hope it helps
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your query is returning a empty record set. To debug it try:

```
$select = $DB->select()
     ->from(array('p' => 'phone_service'))
     ->join(array('u' => 'user_preferences'), 'u.phone_service_id = p.phone_service_id')
     ->where('u.user_preferences_name = ?', 'is_user_package_active')
     ->where('p.user_id = ?', $user_id);
echo $select;
die();
```

This should output the exact query sent to mysql and you could copy-paste it in phpmyadmin/heidisql or whatever you use to manage mysql and see if it returns what you expect. From there you can try to make the query work and then port it back to your php code.